# How to use Community SQLite plugin in MVVMCross

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

In my application I was using the old SQLite-plugin.
Since MVVMCross 3.0.14 this version is deprecated and the Community.Sqlite plugin is advised.

The Community plugin was added via Nuget.

When trying to use the plugin without a bootstrapper, at runtime I get the error:

> Failed to resolve parameter for parameter connectionFactory of type ISQLiteConnectionFactory when creating...

When trying to use the plugin with a bootstrapper, also at runtime, I get the error:

> plugin not registered for type Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite

How should this plugin be used?

-Edit-
This is my bootstrapper code:

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite;
public class SqlitePluginBootstrap : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<PluginLoader>
{
}
```

Comment: For me it worked to simply replace the depreciated plugin with the community equivalent (3.0.14-beta2). Please publish the code for your SQLite bootstrapper.

Comment: I'm at v3.0.13, Nuget doesn't offer me any pre-release updates. I'll add code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, Nuget added a reference to the portable library. I added a reference to the Sqlite.Touch library and then altered my bootstrapper:

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.Touch;
public class SqlitePluginBootstrap : MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction<PluginLoader, Plugin>
{
}
```

This solved the "plugin not registered"-error for me.

Comment: I have the same problem I work with MvvmCross > 3.5 and I need to use Community.Sqlite plugin but when install for nugget I have this error 'Type or namespace Community' not exist in the namespace Cirrious.MvvmCross'

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed - I came across the same issue.
Nuget downloads the right things, but only adds the one reference, as Jacco points out.

It doesn't add the reference to Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.Touch.dll, and it doesn't put the bootstrap in for you automatically.

I have one extra using statement in my bootstrap for MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction. Here's the complete code:

```
using Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.Touch;
public class SqlitePluginBootstrap : MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction<PluginLoader, Plugin>
{
}
```