# MVVM Cross iOS Sqlite issue: Plugin not registered for type Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite (Community Sqlite Plugin version 3.1.1)

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using Xamarin Studio with MVVM Cross 3.5.1 and recently upgraded SQLite to the Community Plugin (version 3.1.1) and although it works fine in Android and Windows Phone 8.1 the iOS project can't use SQLite anymore.

The bootstraper code looks like this out-of-the-box:
using Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins;

```
namespace Compass.Mobile.iOS.Bootstrap {
    public class SqlitePluginBootstrap 
       : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.PluginLoader>
    {
    }
}
```

I looked at Question [20143457](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143457/how-to-use-community-sqlite-plugin-in-mvvmcross) but the code it refers to is no longer applicable.

Has anybody figured out how to resolve this yet?

Comment: It doesn't work. After the unified in iOS you have to use the other plugin for sqlite

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the SQLite-PCL for MvvmCross plugin:  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/tree/master/SQLite-PCL

It is much more up to date. The bootstrap to use for it is:

```
public class SqlitePluginBootstrap
    : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.PluginLoader>
    {}
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears I will have to upgrade my project to MVVM Cross 4.0 beta to support this, and along with the upgrade I need to rewrite some parts of the application since there appear to be some core changes to IMvcxApplication and what not.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you do not bootstrap a **PCL+platform-specific** 
plugin in the **iOS-specific** way.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#how-plugins-are-loaded-)

> Note: on AoT platforms (i.e. MonoTouch/Xamarin.iOS) the bootstrap
>   class used is slightly different - to assist the AoT process, it
>   references classes from both the PCL and the platform specific
>   Assemblies for the plugin like:

```
public class ColorPluginBootstrap
    : MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction<Color.PluginLoader, Color.Touch.Plugin>
{
}
```

instead of the standard

```
public class ColorPluginBootstrap
    : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Color.PluginLoader>
{
}
```